# Unit Testing in Python:: Failure :::

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am running unit testing in python. Here is the code for test script.

```
import json


def test_create_flat(client):
    data = {
        "title": "SDE super",
        "company": "doogle",
        "company_url": "www.doogle.com",
        "location": "USA,NY",
        "description": "python",
        "date_posted": "2022-03-20"
        }
    response = client.post("/flats/create-flat/",json.dumps(data))
    assert response.status_code == 200 
    assert response.json()["company"] == "doogle"
    assert response.json()["description"] == "python"

def test_read_flat(client):     #new test
    data = {
        "title": "SDE super",
        "company": "doogle",
        "company_url": "www.doogle.com",
        "location": "USA,NY",
        "description": "python",
        "date_posted": "2022-03-20"
        }
    response = client.post("/flats/create-flat/",json.dumps(data))

    response = client.get("/flats/get/1/")
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert response.json()['title'] == "SDE super"
```

Here is the result. I couldn't find the reason for the failure on test_read_flat function.

Terminal
-> pytest

```
================================================ test session starts ================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.8, pytest-6.2.5, py-1.10.0, pluggy-1.0.0
rootdir: /Users/ok/Desktop/javasc/backend
plugins: mock-1.13.0, anyio-3.6.2, cov-3.0.0
collected 3 items                                                                                                   

tests/test_routes/test_flats.py .F                                                                            [ 66%]
tests/test_routes/test_users.py .                                                                             [100%]

===================================================== FAILURES ======================================================
__________________________________________________ test_read_flat ___________________________________________________

client = <starlette.testclient.TestClient object at 0x7f89f8f0c8e0>

    def test_read_flat(client):     #new test
        data = {
            "title": "SDE super",
            "company": "doogle",
            "company_url": "www.doogle.com",
            "location": "USA,NY",
            "description": "python",
            "date_posted": "2022-03-20"
            }
        response = client.post("/flats/create-flat/",json.dumps(data))
    
        response = client.get("/flats/get/1/")
>       assert response.status_code == 200
E       assert 404 == 200
E        +  where 404 = <Response [404]>.status_code

tests/test_routes/test_flats.py:30: AssertionError
============================================== short test summary info ==============================================
FAILED tests/test_routes/test_flats.py::test_read_flat - assert 404 == 200
============================================ 1 failed, 2 passed in 0.80s ============================================
(base) ok@Oks-MacBook-Air backend %
```

All three test should have passed. I am new to unit testing I tried and checked all the lines one by one but couldn't see the problem

Comment: In the second test why is this line there `response = client.get("flats/get/1")`? You're setting response twice, that seems like a mistake.

Comment: You are getting `404` errors, are you sure the http requests are correct?

Comment: The reason is that `assert response.status_code == 200` failed.  The status code was actually 404, not 200.  I don't understand how you missed this.  It's right there at the bottom of the output.

Comment: Or is your real question "Why was a 404 response returned"?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I couldn't find the reason for the failure on test_read_flat function." - well, when you **read** the test report, what do you think it's telling you?